# Is it possible to get the placeholder ID from a placeholder in Google Slides?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I've created a text content placeholder in Google Slides by editing the Google Slides theme. I'd like to dynamically insert content into that placeholder and to do that I need to know the placeholder ID.

So I can identify the placeholder,I've inserted the following text into the placeholder "Placeholder 1". I've written a script that then tries to pull the unique ID for that placeholder based on the text inside.

```
function findPlaceholderIdByText() {
  // Google Slides presentation ID
  var presentationId = "1BSmYn9SMbZ9jN4_cwgndSaNDLhite_L8GUiN_V3nTAs"; // Replace with your presentation ID

  // Open the Google Slides presentation
  console.log("Opening the Google Slides presentation...");
  var presentation = SlidesApp.openById(presentationId);
  console.log("Google Slides presentation opened.");

  var slide = presentation.getSlides()[0]; // Assuming you're working with the first slide
  var pageElements = slide.getPageElements();
  
  // Loop through page elements and find the placeholder with the specified text
for (var i = 0; i < pageElements.length; i++) {
    var pageElement = pageElements[i];
    console.log("Checking page element: " + pageElement.getObjectId());
    if (pageElement.asShape().getText().getText() === "Placeholder 1") {
      var placeholderId = pageElement.getObjectId();
      console.log("Found placeholder with text 'Placeholder 1'. Placeholder ID: " + placeholderId);
      break; // Assuming there's only one placeholder with this text
    }
}
}
```

I get the following output

2:28:52 PM  Notice  Execution started

2:28:53 PM  Info    Opening the Google Slides presentation...

2:28:53 PM  Info    Google Slides presentation opened.

2:28:53 PM  Notice  Execution completed

Comment: I've updated my initial question so hopefully should make more sense

Comment: It seems like your issue is with duplicate `.getText()` in your if  statement, how about using `pageElement.asShape().getText().asString().trim() === "Placeholder 1"`?

Comment: I get the same result @SputnikDrunk2 with that update unfortunately

Comment: Please update your question with the necessary data *(e.g. a dummy Slides file that looks similar to your actual slides file)*. This will enable people in the community to fully replicate your issue. From there, they can propose a solution that specifically addresses the problem. Please check [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding your current script. When I saw your showing script, I thought that an error occurred at `pageElement.asShape().getText().getText()`. Because Class SlidesApp.TextRange has no method of `getText`. But, in your showing log, no error occurs. From this situation, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your current script. How about this? I think that in your question, correctly replicating your current issue will lead to a solution. So, can you provide a sample Google Slide and your actual script for replicating it?

Answer (score 0):

Takeshi, as I see SputnikDrunk2 is right.

To get the text you should use `pageElement.asShape().getText().asString()`
but text could not end where you expect and two `\n` could be at the end of "Placeholder 1" when you retreive it.

As SputnikDrunk2 states a `trim()` should do the... trim ;-) you can implemet it with indexOf by

```
pageElement.asShape().getText().asString().indexOf("Placeholder 1") === 0
```

So, as SputnikDrunk2 states:

```
function findPlaceholderIdByText() {
  // Google Slides presentation ID
  var presentationId = "1BSmYn9SMbZ9jN4_cwgndSaNDLhite_L8GUiN_V3nTAs"; // Replace with your presentation ID

  // Open the Google Slides presentation
  console.log("Opening the Google Slides presentation...");
  var presentation = SlidesApp.openById(presentationId);
  console.log("Google Slides presentation opened.");

  var slide = presentation.getSlides()[0]; // Assuming you're working with the first slide
  var pageElements = slide.getPageElements();
  
  // Loop through page elements and find the placeholder with the specified text
for (var i = 0; i < pageElements.length; i++) {
    var pageElement = pageElements[i];
    console.log("Checking page element: " + pageElement.getObjectId());
    if (pageElement.asShape().getText().asString().trim() === "Placeholder 1") {
      var placeholderId = pageElement.getObjectId();
      console.log("Found placeholder with text 'Placeholder 1'. Placeholder ID: " + placeholderId);
      break; // Assuming there's only one placeholder with this text
    }
}
}
```

Should work.

Or...

```
function findPlaceholderIdByText() {
  // Google Slides presentation ID
  var presentationId = "1BSmYn9SMbZ9jN4_cwgndSaNDLhite_L8GUiN_V3nTAs"; // Replace with your presentation ID

  // Open the Google Slides presentation
  console.log("Opening the Google Slides presentation...");
  var presentation = SlidesApp.openById(presentationId);
  console.log("Google Slides presentation opened.");

  var slide = presentation.getSlides()[0]; // Assuming you're working with the first slide
  var pageElements = slide.getPageElements();
  
  // Loop through page elements and find the placeholder with the specified text
for (var i = 0; i < pageElements.length; i++) {
    var pageElement = pageElements[i];
    console.log("Checking page element: " + pageElement.getObjectId());
    if (pageElement.asShape().getText().asString().indexOf("Placeholder 1") === 0) {
      var placeholderId = pageElement.getObjectId();
      console.log("Found placeholder with text 'Placeholder 1'. Placeholder ID: " + placeholderId);
      break; // Assuming there's only one placeholder with this text
    }
}
}
```

Should work too.

Comment: thanks. In this case, I get the console output:

3:35:06 PM Info Opening the Google Slides presentation...
3:35:06 PM Info Google Slides presentation opened.
3:35:07 PM Notice Execution completed

The last two console.logs aren't outputted meaning the for and if statements aren't executing?

Comment: Takeshi, i suggest to log the pageElements.length and presentation name before the loop to be sure that the opened document is the one you think it is.
  console.log(pageElements.length);
  console.log(presentation.getName());